# Batch: move files group without set source/target folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I use this script to move a set of files inside folders generated by script

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\khin\test"
SET "destdir=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\khin\test"
SET /a destcount=0
SET /a maxcount=10
SET /a filecount=maxcount
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 SET /a filecount +=1
 IF !filecount! geq %maxcount% (
  SET /a filecount=0
  SET /a destcount +=1
  MD "%destdir%\folder!destcount!"
 )
 MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\folder!destcount!\"
)
 
GOTO :EOF
```

What is my problem?
I need always to set a source folder and a target folder

```
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\khin\test"
SET "destdir=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\khin\test"
```

**What do I want?**
I want just press on batch .bat (is inside into my folder) where files are ready to be moved without set source/target because I have to repeat this operation for other files in other folders as well.

**example**:

I have 31 files (example). I execute this script and script creates 3 folders. For each folder you find 10 files (except in the fourth folder where you will find 1 file).
To do this, my script need to have source and target to move files. But I want that script generates these folders inside the folder it is in.

Comment: so the script is supposed to guess (correctly), where the files are and where you want them to be? Please clarify.

Comment: I am not sure if you are saying that the batch file will exist within the Source folder or you are saying you want to select a folder and have the batch file execute based on the folder you selected.  If you need to know the script path, that would be `%~dp0`.  If you want to drag and drop a folder onto the batch file then use the command line argument `%1`

Comment: @Stephan  script is in the same folder where are located files ready to be moved. Generally this script you can use it from any location but I copied it before in source folder this script so I don't need to set source/target folder

Comment: @Squashman Yes, i'm saying that the batch file exist within the Source folder. I need to remove from my script `SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\khin\test"
SET "destdir=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\khin\test"`

Comment: `%~dp0` references the folder, where the batch script is located.

Comment: I have 31 files (example). I execute this script and script creates 3 folders. For each folder you find 10 files (except in the fourth folder where you will find 1 file).
To do this, my script need to have source and target to move files. But I want that script generates these folders inside the folder it is in.

Comment: `SET "sourcedir=%~dp0"`

Comment: I change into `SET "sourcedir=%~dp0"`and
`SET "destdir=%~dp0"` and this works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you could do this in PowerShell, it might be something like this. Note that this will -not move the .ps1 script file.

```
$MaxCount = 10
$FileList = Get-ChildItem -File -Path $(Split-Path -Path $PSCommandPath -Parent) |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -ne $(Split-Path -Path $PSCommandPath -Leaf) }

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $FileList.Count; $i++) {
    $DirNum = [Math]::Floor($i / $MaxCount)
    $DirName = Join-Path -Path $(Split-Path -Path $PSCommandPath -Parent) `
        -ChildPath $("Dir" + $DirNum)
    if (-not (Test-Path $DirName)) { mkdir $DirName -WhatIf }
    Move-Item -Path $Filelist[$i].FullName -Destination $DirName -WhatIf
}
```